# How to fix center menu without moving the logo brand to center?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to center my navbar menu , but I don't want my logo navbar brand move too , but I also tried to with text-center , but it seems nothing to work .. I update it the code , and removing the container class , but the third list over the second list

```
.nav.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Header-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-bar-container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
        <li><a href="#">Center 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Center 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Center 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Right</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

my problem after adding

```
.nav.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.nav-bar-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-bar-container{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

[image: center]

Comment: Where is your menu? I can only see a "logo" and email

Comment: my menu is under ``` <div class="wrapper"> ```

Comment: I don't see it in your code...

Comment: Sorry , I updated it

Comment: Can you specify the version of Bootstrap you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend removing the container class and add your own, since it has some `!important` rules. The use

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

```css
.nav.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.nav-bar-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-bar-container{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Header-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-bar-container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
        <li><a href="#">Center 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Center 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Center 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Right</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that one too , but the list is over the second me

Comment: do you want to hide the menu if the screen is small?